# Not desired result from DrawTextA()

Tags: c++, mfc

When calling DrawText() I don't get the result I want. I want the width of the text for a Checkbox control. But it's wider than it should be.
I don't want the part marked with red.

[image]

```
DrawTextA(strText, strlen(strText), *pclRect, DT_CALCRECT | DT_NOPREFIX | DT_SINGLELINE);
int iLength = pclRect->right - pclRect->left;
```

Any idea how I can get the absolute value?
Can I use different flags to get the result I want?

Edit:

```
    SIZE sz;
    HFONT font = (HFONT)pCWnd->GetFont(); //(pCWnd is my CButton)
    HDC hdc = GetDC(NULL);
    SelectObject(hdc, font);

    GetTextExtentPoint32(hdc, strText, strText.GetLength(), &sz);
    ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
```

Comment: You might have the wrong font selected in to `HDC`, then `DrawTextA` returns a different rectangle. You should show more code, also explain what your goal is (normally you don't really need that length, you just need the length of control...)

Comment: The goal is to get rid of the gray background of the text after the last letter, the part marked in red.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775961%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I can't get `GetIdealSize()` to work for some reason.
`CButton* button = new CButton();
SIZE* sz;
button.GetIdealSize(sz);`

'GetIdealSize' : is not a member of 'CButton'

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I've added my try of using `GetTextExtentPoint32` in the question, does that help you?

Comment: @Gernot1976 Yes, in this case it might be so. But when i've a longer string the red part also gets longer.

Comment: Actually use @HansPassant 's suggestion: `Button_GetIdealSize(checkBox->m_hWnd, &size)` it works for Vista and above

Comment: "Identifier not found", I've included `Commctrl.h`. But I read something about minGW-w64, and I have no idea what that is :S

Comment: *"Identifier not found"* This is error from what? Use `CRect rect; checkBox->GetClientRect(&rect);` then `rect.Width()` is the width of the control -- by the way, don't use `GetDC(NULL)` that gets deskop dc. Use `CClientDC dc(this);`  or `CClientDC dc(checkBox);`  see answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple code to get the text length. To do anything useful you need the dimensions of check box, themedata etc.

```
void CMyWnd::foo()
{
    CWnd *check = GetDlgItem(IDC_CHECK1);
    if (check)
    {
        CString str;
        check->GetWindowText(str);

        CClientDC dc(this);
        dc.SelectObject(GetFont());
        int width = dc.GetTextExtent(str).cx; //get width

        //test to see where the lines are
        CRect rcheck;
        check->GetWindowRect(&rcheck); //rect in screen coordinates

        POINT pt = { 0 };
        ScreenToClient(&pt);
        rcheck.OffsetRect(pt);  //rect is relative to top-left of parent

        dc.SelectObject(GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH));
        dc.SelectObject(GetStockObject(BLACK_PEN));

        dc.MoveTo(rcheck.right, rcheck.bottom + 1);
        dc.LineTo(rcheck.right - w, rcheck.bottom + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error in `ScreenToClient`, it takes two arguements `hWnd` and `LPPOINT`. I tried to change `pt` to `LPPOINT` but then `OffsetRect` complains. I also get an error in `w` undeclared identifier.

Comment: That's a window class. I update the answer to read `CMyWnd::foo()` run it in your window class

Comment: I only used the part until `int width...` thats all I needed, thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the problem isn't that there's *no* way to do this... it's that there are *many*.

I would look into using [GetTextExtentPoint32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144938(v=vs.85).aspx), the more historical [GetTextExtent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7e878zz(VS.71).aspx), or you could even ask [DrawText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6x7y2a4.aspx) to do it too... like this:
   CRect rect(0,0,0,0);
   m_hControl.GetDC()->DrawText(szString, &rect, DT_CALCRECT);

Comment: `GetTextExtentPoint32()` returns the same result as `DrawTextA()` atm